# Counting based on recent date sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to count unique users that made a transaction from whatever device they are register to.

Here is my query :

```
select Distinct 
    username , 
    case 
       when user_agent like '%Android%' then 'Android'
       when user_agent like '%iPhone%' OR user_agent like '%Iphone%' then     'IOS'
       else 'Internet Banking'
    end as type, 
    min(time)
from
    activeUsers
group by 
    (1, 2);
```

However, in the result set I get this :

[image: Image Showing query results]

I want for example user ujvs24hxen9/abdallah to be counted based on  the latest date , for example to be counted once only in internetbanking and not in internetbanking and ios.

How can I do this? I am using postgresql

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PostgreSQL's `DISTINCT ON (username)` to get only one record per user. Use the `ORDER BY` clause to get the desired record per user (i.e. the latest) first:

```
select distinct on (username)
  username,
  case when user_agent like '%Android%' then 'Android'
       when user_agent like '%iPhone%' 
         or user_agent like '%Iphone%' then  'IOS'
       else 'Internet Banking'
  end as type,
  time
from activeusers
order by username, time desc;
```

As to your own query:

- `GROUP BY xyz` means you want one result row per xyz. In your query you group by the first two columns, so you get a result row per user and type. But you only want a result row per user. Hence having type in your `GROUP BY` clause makes no sense.
- `DISTINCT` removes duplicate rows from the results. As you group by user and type and both of these columns get selected, there can be no duplicates; these two columns make each row distinct already, so applying `DISTINCT` on these rows is superfluous.
- And there is no place where you even try to find the latest time per user and use this to access the desired record. So obviously this query cannot work.

Comment: I want to count usernames and group them by type , This query works fine but i cant count usernames and group them by os type

Comment: You can build up on above query's results: `select type, count(*) from ( <above query> ) x group by type;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select Distinct username , 
Case When user_agent like '%Android%' then 'Android'
when user_agent like '%iPhone%' OR user_agent like '%Iphone%' then     'IOS'
else 'Internet Banking'
END as type , time
from activeUsers a1
where time = (select max(time) from activeUsers a2 where a1.username = a2.username)
```

I am assuming when you say 'latest' time that you mean max no min time.

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct on (username)
    username,
    case
        when user_agent like '%Android%' then 'Android'
        when user_agent like '%iPhone%' OR user_agent like '%Iphone%' then 'IOS'
        else 'Internet Banking'
    end as type 
    time
from activeUsers
order by username, time desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `row_number` window function to just get the last transaction per user:

```
SELECT username, type
FROM   (SELECT username , 
               CASE WHEN user_agent LIKE '%Android%' THEN 'Android'
                    WHEN user_agent LIKE '%iPhone%' OR 
                         user_agent LIKE '%Iphone%' THEN 'IOS'
                    ELSE 'Internet Banking'
        END AS type,
        time
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY username ORDER BY time DESC) AS rn
FROM    activeUsers) t
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the answer given by @Mureinik would be to use a subquery to identify the latest time for each user, and then use it to restrict the original table to the records we actually want in the result set.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT username, MAX(time) AS max_time
    FROM activeUsers
    GROUP BY username
)

SELECT t1.username,
       CASE WHEN t1.user_agent LIKE '%Android%' THEN 'Android'
            WHEN t1.user_agent LIKE '%iPhone%' OR t1.user_agent LIKE '%Iphone%' THEN 'IOS'
            ELSE 'Internet Banking'
       END AS type
FROM activeUsers t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.username = t2.username AND
       t1.time     = t2.max_time
```